# xslt transformation in java , attribute value not encoded

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am writing a java program where in some cases I have to perform a xslt transformation.

In this case i need to add an attribute named type at the level of the work.
Its value should be the same as the value of the element ns2:type_work

For example:

```
<ns2:work>
     <ns2:type_work>PROP</ns2:type_work>
     <ns2:identifier_work>2017/375/943030</ns2:identifier_work>
<ns2:work>
```

should become

```
<ns2:work type="PROP">
     <ns2:type_work>PROP</ns2:type_work>
     <ns2:identifier_work>2017/375/943030</ns2:identifier_work>   
<ns2:work>
```

I have made the following XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="ns2:work">
    <ns2:work>
       <xsl:attribute name="type" select="ns2:type_work/node()" />
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|child::node()" />
    </ns2:work>
</xsl:template>
```

and I apply it using the proper java functios (javax.xml.transform.), 
I get no erros, 
the attribute -type- is created 
**but it is empty.**

Does it have to do something with the XSLT version is my xslt not compatible with 1.0?
How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 1.0, then the code needs to look like this, as `select` is not valid on `xsl:attribute` in XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:attribute name="type">
   <xsl:value-of select="ns2:type_work/node()" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

(Note that you can just do `<xsl:value-of select="ns2:type_work" />` here)

Better still, use Attribute Value Templates

```
<ns2:work type="{ns2:type_work}" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|child::node()" />
</ns2:work>
```

Comment: I suspect the stylesheet says version="2.0" and is being run with a 1.0 processor. A 1.0 processor given a stylesheet that says version="2.0" is supposed to ignore all attributes it doesn't understand, which would account for the absence of any error here.